# C# How can I remove spaces before sentence ending

Tags: c#

I was trying to remove spaces before sentence ending but had no success. I was thinking of doing it with Split function but it didn't go well. The only thing I succeeded at was adding spaces after sentence ending. Here is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog dlgOpen = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();
            if (dlgOpen.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(dlgOpen.FileName);
                string dat1 = sr.ReadToEnd();
                string dat2 = Path.GetDirectoryName(dlgOpen.FileName);
                string dat3 = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(dlgOpen.FileName);
                string dat4 = Path.GetExtension(dlgOpen.FileName);

                dat2 = dat2 + "/" + dat3 + "_norm" + dat4;
                sz1(ref dat1);
                Console.Write(dat1);
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(dat2, false);
                sw.WriteLine(dat1);
                sw.Flush();
                sw.Close();

                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
        static void sz1(ref string dat1)
        {
            char[] ArrayCharacters = { '.', ':', ',', ';', '!', '?' };
            int i = -1;
            dat1 = dat1.Trim();

            for (int k = 0; k < dat1.Length; k++)
            {
                dat1 = dat1.Replace("  ", " ");
            }

            do
            {
                i = dat1.IndexOfAny(ArrayCharacters, i + 1);

                if (i != -1)
                {
                    dat1 = dat1.Insert((i + 1), " ");
                    dat1 = dat1.Replace("  ", " ");
                }
            } while (i != -1);

            do
            {
                i = dat1.IndexOfAny(ArrayCharacters, i + 1);

                if (i != -1)
                {
                    dat1 = dat1.Insert((i - 1), "  ");
                    dat1 = dat1.Replace("  ", " ");
                    dat1 = dat1.Remove(i - 1, 1);
                }
            } while (i != -1);
        }
```

Comment: You should use regex.

Comment: I haven't learned regex so I am not allowed to use it on my program, I have to solve it with string function.

Comment: Why not `"someString".TrimEnd()`?

Comment: `Replace` will replace **all** instances of the first string with the second string. You don't need to call it in a loop.

Comment: The placing of artificial constraints on a solution (i.e. *"I haven't learned regex so I am not allowed to use it on my program"*) is of little benefit to future users, and should therefore be discouraged. Hence, I'm downvoting. I'll probably do this for sub-optimal solutions that pander to this requirement too.

Comment: To clarify, are you trying to remove spaces between the last word of a sentence and a punctuation mark like `?` or `.`?

Answer (score 2):

One option is using regex:

```
string pattern = "\\s+$";
string replacement = "";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
string result = rgx.Replace(dat1, replacement);
```

Comment: Saw the comment saying you can't use regex after posting this.  I'm going to leave this up, as it is a real-world solution.  As others have noted, string.TrimEnd() also works.  However regex is much more flexible in case you have other characters to consider.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just learning programming, then one solution that you should be familiar with is to use a loop to walk the string one character at a time, and since we're examining the end of the string, it makes sense to walk it backwards.

I'm assuming from your code (though it would be nice if you clarified it in your question) that you have a set of characters that are allowed at the end of a sentence, and you would like to leave these characters alone, but remove any additional spaces.

The logic, then, would be to start from the end of the string, and if a character is a valid ending character leave it alone. Otherwise, if it's a space, remove it. And finally, if it's neither then we're done.

Below is a method that uses this logic, along with a `StringBuilder` variable that is used to store the result. Starting at the end of the string, we capture the last characters, adding them to the result if they're valid and skipping them if they're spaces, until we reach a "regular" character, at which point we keep the rest of the string:

```
static string TrimEndSpaces(string input)
{
    // If the input is null, there's nothing to do - just return null
    if (input == null) return input;

    // Our array of valid ending punctuation
    char[] validEndingPunctuation = { '.', ':', ',', ';', '!', '?' };

    // This will contain our final result
    var result = new StringBuilder();

    // Walk backwards through the input string
    for (int i = input.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (validEndingPunctuation.Contains(input[i]))
        {
            // Valid character, so add it and keep going backwards
            result.Insert(0, input[i]);
            continue;
        }

        if (input[i] == ' ')
        {
            // Space character at end - skip it
            continue;
        }

        // Regular character found - we're done. Add the rest of the string
        result.Insert(0, input.Substring(0, i + 1));
        break;
    }

    return result.ToString();
}
```

And here is an example usage, with some test sentences with varying endings of spaces, valid characters, null strings, empty strings, etc:

```
private static void Main()
{
    var testInput = new List<string>
    {
        null,
        "",
        "       ",
        "Normal sentence test.",
        "Test with spaces   .",
        "Test with multiple ending chars  !?!?!",
        "Test with only spaces at end   ",
        "Test with spaces after punctuation.   ",
        "Test with mixed punctuation and spaces ! ? ! ? ! "
    };

    foreach (var test in testInput)
    {
        // Format output so we can "see" null and empty strings
        var original = test ?? "<null>";
        if (original.Length == 0) original = "<empty>";

        // Show original and the result. Wrap result in <> so we know where it ends.
        Console.WriteLine($"{original.PadRight(50, '-')} = <{TrimEndSpaces(test)}>");
    }

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to remove them from the end, you can use:

```
if(myString.EndsWith(" ") == true)
{
    myString = myString.TrimEnd();
}
```

Of course, you will need to consider the ending symbol ".", "!" or "?", you might want to exclude that char if the spaces are just before it.

Another approach would be:

```
var keepTrimming = true;

while(keepTrimming == true)
{
    if(myString.EndsWith(" ") == true)
    {
        myString= myString.Remove(myString.Length - 1);
    }
    else
    {
        keepTrimming = false
    }
}
```

Comment: .NET strings are immutable, so this will not work.  You would need to at least assign the result of `TrimEnd` to a variable.